# EJS if condition never met

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

In my ejs file, there is a if condition that checks user login status.

If user is logged in, display welcome + "displayName", and logout button

If user if not logged in, display login button.

```
<% if(typeof displayName == 'string' && displayName) { %>
      <li class="navbar-text">
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Welcome, 
        <%= displayName %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="/logout" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout</a
        >
      </li>
      <% } else { %>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="/login" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></i>
             Login</a>
        </li>
      <% } %>
```

The thing is, I am able to login, but the welcome and logout button is never displayed, it still remains as "login". I have to manually type /logout in the url bar to logout.

I put my displayName in the console log, which clearly showed it after login:
[image]

As you can see, it recorded my displayName, which is a string.

Can anyone elaborate why is the if condition not working?

Comment: Please share the code that renders the template. Are you sure the template is receiving an object with `displayName` property?

Comment: Hi @sdgluck , thank you for the hint. As you said, I forgot to pass the displayName property in my `res.render`, the problem is solved now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I forgot to pass in `displayName` property in my renders

After I added : `displayName: req.user ? req.user.displayName : ""`, everything works fine now.